# Trying to make Check reCaptcha Mixin for login view- django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, recaptcha

I am trying to make a mixin which will check for valid reCaptcha.
I am new in django, I tried to make it with what I know

It is checking correctly but problem is with Permission.
When it redirect me again to login page immediately it get authenticated and redirect to Dashboard, means success page.

Have a look at mixin.

```
class CheckRecaptchaMixin(AccessMixin):

    error_message = 'Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again.'

    def get_error_message(self):
        return self.error_message

    def handle_not_valid_recaptcha(self):

        message = self.get_error_message()
        if self.raise_exception:
            raise PermissionDenied(message)
        messages.error(self.request, message)
        print('login redirect')
        return redirect_to_login(self.request.get_full_path(), self.get_login_url(), self.get_redirect_field_name())


    def dispatch(self,request, *args, **kwargs):

        request.recaptcha_is_valid = None
        if request.method == 'POST':
            recaptcha_response = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
            data = {
                'secret': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
                'response': recaptcha_response
            }
            r = requests.post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', data=data)
            result = r.json()
            if result['success']:
                print('This is success')
                request.recaptcha_is_valid = True
            else:
                print('This is error')
                request.recaptcha_is_valid = False
                self.handle_not_valid_recaptcha()

        return super(CheckRecaptchaMixin, self).dispatch(request,*args, **kwargs)
```

In my views.py

```
class UserLoginView(CheckRecaptchaMixin,LoginView):
   template_name = 'accounts/login.html'
   redirect_field_name='next'
```

When reCaptcha is correct it is printing `This is success` only and when reCaptcha is incorrect it is printing `This is error` and `login redirect`.

This means it is handling reCaptcha successfully but not redirecting to login page, one more important thing to notice, on my logout page I see `error_message` that I have defined in mixin('Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again.')

Answer (score 0):

What I did for not getting authenticate is add a error in form by `get_form` method, here is working mixin.

```
class CheckRecaptchaMixin(AccessMixin):

    error_message = 'Invalid reCAPTCHA. Please try again.'
    not_activated_redirect = ''
    def get_error_message(self):
        return self.error_message

    def dispatch(self,request, *args, **kwargs):

        request.recaptcha_is_valid = None
        if request.method == 'POST':
           recaptcha_response = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
            data = {
                'secret': settings.GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY,
                'response': recaptcha_response
            }
            r = requests.post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', data=data)
            result = r.json()
            if result['success']:
                request.recaptcha_is_valid = True
            else:
                request.recaptcha_is_valid = False

        return super(CheckRecaptchaMixin, self).dispatch(request,*args, **kwargs)

    def get_form(self,form_class=None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)
        if self.request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
            if not self.request.recaptcha_is_valid:
                form.add_error(None,self.get_error_message())
        return form
```

If anyone have better option to do so, he/she can answer me, thanks.